# GWT (Google Web Toolkit) Designer not working on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java, eclipse, development, javascript

The GWT Desinger is not working on Ubuntu 12.10. It worked on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed the Eclipse Plugin as described on the [GWT Homepate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download)
If I want to open the Design-View (for an xml-GWT-File), Eclipse crashes (prompt closing of the application).

I found [this two workarounds](http://www.elgali.net/2012/05/14/gwt-designer-eclipse-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04/) for which are for 12.04 (but on 12.04 i did not need this to get it working - it worked out of the box for me). I tried them on my 12.10 Ubuntu but they are not working. But I have to say that I can't find the "Use WebKit for rendering GWT UI (if available)"-Flag.

What can I do to get the GWT Designer working? I tested it successfully again on a 12.04 Ubuntu VMware image. If I don't get a solution, I have to downgrade my Ubuntu to 12.04 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works (but only with Eclipse 3.7.2):

Download [Eclipse Classic 3.7.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2).

Install [GWT Designer via Plugin-Link in Eclipse as described here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner).

Install [the GWT SDK (and the rest) via Plugin-Link in Eclipse as described here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download)

Execute [Workaround 2 from this page](http://www.elgali.net/2012/05/14/gwt-designer-eclipse-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

---

You can find more information about [this issue in this bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7232).

Answer (score 0):

Installing these packages worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04 (64bits) with STS 2.9.2 based on Eclipse 3.7.2:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu48
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Inspired by http://elgali.net/2012/05/14/gwt-designer-eclipse-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04/