# GWT (Google Web Toolkit) designer not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: java, eclipse, development, javascript, web-development

On 13.04 the GWT designer is not working on Eclipse 4.2 and Eclipse 3.7. If I want to switch in the design-mode after executing [Workaround 2 from this page](http://elgali.net/2012/05/14/gwt-designer-eclipse-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04/), Eclipse crashes and is closing automatically.

I asked [this question for 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221893/gwt-google-web-toolkit-designer-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-10), where it works for my answer on 12.10. I tested both answers from this question and none is working on 13.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a 'clean' workaround [tested on Ubuntu 13.04 (amd64) & Eclipse Kepler]

As it seems, GWT (also SWT) needs an older libwebkitgtk1.0 to run the designer.

So, assuming you already have the 13.04 Ubuntu repository 'libwebkitgtk1.0' (v.1.10.x) installed (as a dependency of Gimp for example), and don't want to mess with it:

1) Download the following (from launchpad.net) - BUT DO NOT INSTALL THEM:

- libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
- libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_1.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb

2) Open the 2 files downloaded with Archive manager

3) Create folder $HOME/.eclipse/lib

4) Extract the 'lib' folders contents of the 2 deb files in the folder created

5) Launch eclipse with the following command line (from within the eclipse folder):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.eclipse/lib ./eclipse

6) Switch to the designer tab - should work.

Basically, what you do is forcing eclipse to first check '$HOME/.eclipse/lib' folder for any needed lib and later the /usr/lib - so you place there the older libs and picks them instead of the system installed ones (and the system is still clean/untouched)

(Just a notice - this is not a fix - its a workaround)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem like that, Eclipse just crashed suddenly. I upgraded to 4.3M7 and now it works. here's the link: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

You might have to download the addons allover again.
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7

Comment: 4.3M7 did not solved the problem.  After clicking to switch in the designer mode, Eclipse crashes.